# Why is the current dropping but not the voltage when I've added in a resistor?

Tags: voltage

I've made a 18v guitar amp from some spare parts, and I'm powering it using a power bank with a 5v/2.4a usb output and a [buck booster](https://www.amazon.co.uk/DollaTek-Regulator-3-5V-12V-1-2V-24V-Converter/dp/B081JN757V/ref=sr_1_14?dchild=1&keywords=usb%20dc%20converter&qid=1634119729&qsid=260-3889953-9058237&sr=8-14&sres=B07RGB2HB6%2CB08L9BRDGF%2CB07VPH28LC%2CB07WCTX1HL%2CB087R8QVLX%2CB08TZVY8SP%2CB07JVJ5S2V%2CB08JLT8S1L%2CB07RDL8C9K%2CB081JN757V%2CB07XT8V97Y%2CB07H6KXGDW%2CB08F9QYJV2%2CB07XLM3W79%2CB08SM4RV36%2CB071FT57SV) set to put out 18v. However, the amp causes a surge that puts the power bank to sleep. But this doesn't happen if I start the buck booster on 9v and manually adjust it up to 18v. The buck booster, however, is going to be hidden inside an enclosure so I won't be able to do this in practice.

My work around is to put a resistor in series after the buck booster that will bring down the voltage to 9v. It'll be on a switch that can remove from the circuit allowing the full 18v to be applied once the surge has passed. I've calculated the resistor needed to drop 9v/2.4a is 4ohm/25w and, as luck would have it, I've got one.

My problem is I've put the resistor on the +ve lead from the buck booster and using my DMM I'm measuring ~18v still. The current has gone down though, from 2.4a to 0.5a. What's going on? Am I missing something fundamental in electronics?

Comment: Please show a schematic of *where* you're measuring voltages and currents. I would expect that even with a resistor added to a *load*, the output of the buck converter will remain at 18V, but it's hard to tell when we don't have a precise knowledge of which nodes you actually measured.

Comment: "*Am I missing something fundamental in electronics?*" Yes. For one, you never actually mentioned where you measured what you measured or what was connected at the time in your last paragraph.

Comment: Most likely either the powerbank or the booster module are not compliant USB devices - either the booster takes in larger surge than expected or the powerbank can't handle an expected surge. My bet is the booster is non compliant, or you have some exceptionally large capacitance at the booster output. Which you don't mention. Post the schematics of your circuit.

Comment: You wouldn't see a voltage drop before the resistor, you would see it after it as well as across it. If the resistor doesn't work try an inductor instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a schematic. First I set up the POWER BANK and USB BUCK BOOSTER (set to output 18v) and with DMM set to 20v measured across the + and - outputs of the buck boosters, which gave the reading ~17.8v. Then I set the DMM to 10a and again measured across the buck boosters + and - outputs which gave a reading of ~2.4a. I then repeated this process but with a 4ohm/25w resistor attached in series to the + output of the buck booster resulting in the readings ~17.8/~0.6a.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some misconceptions, measured things wrong or exceeding some maximum ratings of some part of the circuit.

First of all, the powerbank can output 5V at 2.4A which is 12 watts. The booster is only capable of 3 watt output at 18V, which is about 160mA. There is no way the circuit can output 2.4A at 18V. So the amplifier must be rated to work at below 160mA at 18V.

Another thing is that the product website you linked to has the instructions for usage. They say connect input supply first and then connect output supply. Basically you are violating those instructions if you keep the output connected while connecting the input supply, so since the product is used against the instructions it does not need to work properly.

Comment: I do connect the input supply first and then engage the amp circuit. Yes, there's a chance I'm measuring the current incorrectly, I am new to electronics and have only just started using a DMM. But I feel confident that I am measuring the voltage correctly, and I'm surprised that the 4ohm/25w resistor doesn't appear to have any effect on it. It's a big fat 'cement' wire wound resistor.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 12W 5V source and an 18V output on a booster rated for only 2W to 3W meaning the secondary steady current support is only 150 mA or so. But the caps in your Amp when turned On draw more than the secondary current limit with 18V. then adding a series resistor allows th caps to charge up slower but it's final draw only seems to be 500mA , so it should be getting hot as that implies 9W and they suggest please use less than 3W or add a heatsink or fan.

- bottom line is you got the wrong type of booster for your amp that cannot provide enough startup current or does not have a slow ramp "soft start feature"

All boosters like transformers have lower secondary current at higher voltage, but this one can store energy and start it at 9V so leave it where it works. (For now and report the temperature if hot )

Comment: It does work at 18v if I start at 9v and adjust the trimpot up. Are you saying that the amp might be drawing more current than the booster can supply or at least supply safely?

Comment: Also, I have another 5v/2.4a power bank (of a different brand) that I've used with the buck booster and amp and this one does not go to sleep when the booster is set to 18v and the amp is engaged.

Comment: Yes it is common to have surge issues with certain combinations of buck and boost in series